# python-telegram-bot: unsupported operand type(s) for &=: 'function' and '_UpdateType'

Tags: python, telegram, traceback, operands

An error pops up in the python-telegram-bot library when the bot starts.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telegram/ext/messagehandler.py", line 131, in __init__
    self.filters &= Filters.update
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &=: 'function' and '_UpdateType'
 unsupported operand type(s) for &=: 'function' and '_UpdateType'
```

in messagehandler.py

```
    if message_updates is False and channel_post_updates is False and edited_updates is False:
        raise ValueError(
            'message_updates, channel_post_updates and edited_updates are all False')
    self.filters = filters
    if self.filters is not None:
        self.filters &= Filters.update
    else:
        self.filters = Filters.update
```

Comment: Can you share your code?